# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS with apache and certbot

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, apache2, certbot

So I did the http to https redirect thing and everything works fine, but when I go to postman and let's say I have a post method and I put http://api.domain/addDevice, it should redirect to a POST method https://api.domain/addDevice but it redirect me to a GET method https://api.domain/addDevice cause I think it is the default one.

Do I need to change something in the sites-available, sites-enabled of apache2 or somewhere else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is sadly quite normal behaviour - for POST to POST redirect please use http status 307  not the default 302 (as 302 is undefined for other methods than GET and therefore mostly implemented in a way it always redirected from any method to GET method only).

307 status was invented to redirect from method to the same method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307